# Griffiths Introduction to Quantum Mechanics Ed3, Problem 1.5 b)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises

Where I'm going wrong?

$A = \sqrt{\lambda}$, $\lambda$ is a positive real constant.

$$
<x> = \left| A \right|^2 \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x e^{-2 \lambda \left|x\right|}\,dx
$$
$$
= \left| \sqrt{\lambda} \right|^2 \Big\{ \int_{- \infty}^{0} x e^{2 \lambda x}\,dx + \int_{0}^{+\infty} x e^{-2 \lambda x}\,dx \Big\}
$$
$$
= \lambda \Big\{ e^{2 \lambda x} \Big( \frac{2 \lambda x - 1}{4 \lambda^2} \Big) \Big\}\Big|_{-\infty}^{0} + \frac{1}{4 \lambda^2}
$$
$$
= \lambda \Big\{ e^{2 \lambda x} \Big( \frac{x}{2 \lambda} - \frac{1}{4 \lambda^2} \Big) \Big|_{-\infty}^{0} + \frac{1}{4 \lambda^2} \Big\}
$$
$$
= e^{2 \lambda x} \Big( \frac{x}{2} - \frac{1}{4 \lambda} \Big) \Big|_{-\infty}^{0} + \frac{1}{4 \lambda}
$$

$$
= e^0 \Big( \frac{0}{2} - \frac{1}{4 \lambda} \Big) - e^{-\infty} \Big( \frac{-\infty}{2} - \frac{1}{4 \lambda} \Big) + \frac{1}{4 \lambda}
$$
$$
= -\frac{1}{4 \lambda} - \frac{1}{e^{\infty}} \Big( \frac{- \infty}{2} - \frac{1}{4 \lambda} \Big) + \frac{1}{4 \lambda}
$$
$$
= - \frac{1}{4 \lambda} - \Big( \frac{-\infty}{\infty} - 0 \Big) + \frac{1}{4 \lambda}
$$

The answer should be $0$, but obviously I'm not getting there.

Comment: In the second line, try a change of variables $y \equiv -x$ in either the first or second integral and see what happens.

Comment: One easy way is just to say that the integrand is odd around $x=0$. Then it immediately follows that the integral vanishes. If you take this as known mathematics of course

Answer (score 1):

### When you wrote down $e^{-\infty}$

What you did there is not how we compute limits that go to infinity, or improper integrals as they are formally called.
$$
e^{-\infty} \Big( \frac{-\infty}{2} - \frac{1}{4 \lambda} \Big)$$
This, should have been written as
$$
\lim_{x\to-\infty} e^{x} \Big( \frac{x}{2} - \frac{1}{4 \lambda} \Big)
$$
which can be evaluated as follows

> \begin{align}\lim_{x\to-\infty} e^{x} \Big( \frac{x}{2} - \frac{1}{4 \lambda} \Big) &= \lim_{x\to\infty} e^{-x} \Big( \frac{-x}{2} - \frac{1}{4 \lambda} \Big) \\&= \lim_{x\to\infty} \Big( \frac{-x}{2e^x} - \frac{1}{4 \lambda e^x} \Big) \\&= \lim_{x\to\infty} \Big( \frac{-x}{2e^x}  \Big)- 0 \\&= \lim_{x\to\infty} \Big( \frac{-1}{2e^x} \Big) \text{ by L'Hôpitals rule}\\&= 0\end{align}